# Binding the properties of a user control to the properties of the parent

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I am developing a WPF application in VB.net. In this application:

- I have several user controls. Each user control is bound to some properties of it (`user control properties`). So `DataContext` of each user control is set to itself.
- These user controls are used in a window. The window have some other properties (`window properties`).

What I want to do, is binding some of the elements of the user controls to my `window properties`, so that whenever one of my `window properties` is changed, the elements in the user controls get updated.

I have seen several questions and articles, saying that it should be possible with Dependency Property, however, I could not get it to work.

I already have a solution, in which I update the properties in code, however, I want it to be done automaticly in xaml.

I'd be very thankful for any help.

### ________________________________________________________

**UPDATE**: I tried the suggested solutions, but I still cannot get it to work.

Here is a minimal example of what I have:

In my example:

- `BackgroundColor` is a property defined in the user control.
- `Text` is a property defined in the window.

If I create a `ucLabel` (my user contro) in the window, I can bind either the value of `BackgroundColor` or `Text`. In the xaml file of my window I have examples of both cases.

I don't get what I'm missing, that I cannot bind all properties.

**User Control xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucLabel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProject"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Label Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
</Grid>
```

**User Control code behind**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ucLabel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _backgroundColor As Brush

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

    Public Property BackgroundColor As Brush
        Get
            Return Brushes.LightBlue
        End Get
        Set(value As Brush)
            _backgroundColor = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("BackgroundColor")
        End Set
    End Property

#Region "Property Changed"
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(info As [String])
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

**Main Window xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertyTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--here the user control has *only* the correct Background-->
    <local:ucLabel Grid.Row="0"/>

    <!--here the user control has *only* the correct Text-->
    <local:ucLabel Grid.Row="1" 
                   Content="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window } }"/>
</Grid>
```

**Main Window code behind**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _text As String

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

    Public Property Text As String
        Get
            Return "This is a test Text"
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _text = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text")
        End Set
    End Property

#Region "Property Changed"
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(info As [String])
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The user controls that I have used in my window, have either the correct Background Color, or the correct text.

When you set the `Content` of the `UserControl`, you are effectively "overriding" the `Label` you have defined in the XAML markup of it.

You could add a `UCText` property to the `UserControl` and set this one in the window.

**UC xaml:**

```
<Label Background="{Binding BackgroundColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
       Content="{Binding UCText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

**UC Code behind:**

```
Public Shared ReadOnly UCTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UCText", GetType(String), GetType(ucLabel))

Public Property UCText As String
    Get
        Return _uctext
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _uctext = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("UCText")
    End Set
End Property
```

**Window:**

```
<local:ucLabel Grid.Row="1" UCText="{Binding WinText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window } }"/>
```

Comment: And should I define a Dependency Property anywhere? I defined a `UCText` property in the user control, and a `WinText` property in the window. I have `<Label  Content="{Binding UCText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />` in my UC, and `<local:ucLabel UCText="{Binding WinText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />` in my windw. However:

Comment: The only case that I can get it running is that I define a DependencyProperty in my UC like this:  `Public Shared UCTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("UCText", GetType(String), GetType(UserControl))`.  This compiles correctly, although I get an error in the xaml of my window: `'UCText' property was already registered by 'UserControl'.`

Comment: Ok, I solved it by registering the Dependency property with ucLabel and not UserControl. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> `DataContext` of each user control is set to itself

This is why you don't ever do that. You broke your usercontrols when you did that.

Instead, comment out that DataContext line, and use `{Binding UserCtlProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}` bindings inside the UserControl XAML.

Then the Window should be responsible for binding its own properties to those of the UserControl, again using RelativeSource:

```
<local:MyUserControl 
    SomeProperty="{Binding SomeWindowProp, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately, It's still not working. I updated the question explaining what I have now after trying your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to a property of the parent window using a `RelativeSource`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomePropertyOfTheWindow, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately I still cannot use the values of the corresponding properties. I have updated the question. I'd be thankful if you could have a look on it.

Comment: Your comment say that "here the user control has the correct Text". So what exactly is your current issue?

Comment: The user controls that I have used in my window, have *either* the correct Background Color, *or* the correct Text. I correct my comments in the question. So the problem is that I cannot have them both at the same time. (Both = the property from the user control and the property from the window)

Comment: That's because you set the Content property of the UC to a string. See my answer.